# Patching an Android app

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have an Android app with an expansion file already attached. This is all working fine. 
The file is: main.2.com.mydomain.myapp.obb

I want to update some assets in my app so I planned on adding a patch expansion file. Going by the next version iteration this file was: patch.10.com.mydomain.myapp.obb

I've uploaded an alpha build and I can see the files are downloading successfully. The assets in question are videos so I have the following code to access them:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile= null;
AssetFileDescriptor fd= null;

try {
    expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getApplicationContext(),2,10);
    fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("myvideo.mp4");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My understanding is that the `getAPKExpansionZipFile` call will merge the two expansion files but my questions are:

1. If my patch file contains a file of the same name as the original main expansion, will the patch file version take precedent or should I have new filenames in my patch file (e.g. patch_myvideo.mp4)
2. How do I know the video will be correctly loaded from the patch file? I tried checking the AssetFileDescriptor offsets (start, length etc..) but it was the same with and without the patch file call.

Would love to know if I'm on the right track here! 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: In addition to the above, I've noticed something in the `APKExpansionSupport.java` under Google's `com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile`.


There is a line:
    if ( patchVersion > 0 ) {
        String strPatchPath = expPath + File.separator + "patch." + **mainVersion** + "." + packageName + ".obb";

Should this not use **patchVersion** ?